# How can I make a div in a parent flex box div, slide in from the left?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, transition

I have two divs that are side by side in a flex box, and I am trying to make the left div slide in after being called by a JavaScript function and then have the right div resize to be next to the left div.

I have never done any css transitions before so I don't really know where to start. I am using the bootstrap CSS library

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.brand {
  font-family: "Rock Salt", sans-serif;
}

.leftside {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #DEE2E6;
}

.rightside {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
}

.leftside::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
  <div class="leftside">

    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Product title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-body-secondary">$50</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the product title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
    <div class="card" style="width: calc(50% - 4rem);position: absolute; bottom: 2rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title"><span id="brand">Store Name Here</span></h2>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use a basic css transition but it didn't really get the effect I wanted and was very snappy. The code above is the base without the css transition I tried.

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using, can you edit the Snippet I created from your code to include a link to that version and verify that your code is reproducing your problem accurately?

Answer (score 0):

To change the position of these two divs you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse;` but this property will not work with transition. Because transitions only work when two quantified values change. This is my solution:

Add these codes to your css file:

```css
@keyframes left_to_right {
    from {
        left: 0;
    }

    to {
        left: 50%;
    }
}

@keyframes right_to_left {
    from {
        right: 0;
    }

    to {
        right: 50%;
    }
}

.parent-transitions {
    transition: all 2s;
    position: relative;
}

.right-transitions {
    transition: all 2s;
    position: relative;
    animation: right_to_left 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.left-transitions {
    transition: all 2s;
    position: relative;
    animation: left_to_right 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

also add these codes to a JavaScript file:

```js
let rightside = document.querySelector(".rightside")
let leftside = document.querySelector(".leftside")
let fisrtDiv = document.querySelector("div")

function start() {
    fisrtDiv.classList.add("parent-transitions")
    rightside.classList.add("right-transitions")
    leftside.classList.add("left-transitions")
}
```

finally run this function in your Console.

Comment: Amazing. This worked perfectly and helped me out alot. Thank you!

Comment: @JacobAustin Your welcome. If the solution solves your problem could you validate it using the tic button next to the arrow voting buttons? (: